# How to test toggling fullscreen on/off in protractor

Tags: protractor

I am new to industry and looking for assistance to test switching fullscreen on / off using protractor. 
Like for example click to turn full screen on and click to turn full screen off.

I googled a bit and only found the following which is setting the browser to default full screen but not what I am looking for

```
browser.manage().window().maximize();
```

Appreciate any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

If you are using chrome/chromium need to add in protractor config flag:

```
export const config = {
    capabilities: {
        chromeOptions: {
            args: ['--start-fullscreen']
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But I dont want to start the browser in fullscreen. I am trying to validate if browser has gone fullscreen when I click on fullscreen button in my application.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to achieve this functionality by getting the current size of the screen, maximizing and then comparing to your original size.

```
    let currentSize = await browser.manage().window().getSize();
    console.log('current size: ', currentSize);
    await browser.manage().window().maximize();
    let maximisedSize = await browser.manage().window().getSize();
    console.log('max size: ', maximisedSize);
    if (currentSize !== maximisedSize) console.log('Window was not maxmized')
```

I haven't used the .then syntax in a while but you should be able to achieve similar functionality with

```
    browser.manage().window().getSize().then(originalSize => {
        browser.manage().window().maximize().then(() => {
            browser.manage().window().getSize().then(newSize => {
                if(originalSize !== newSize) console.log('Window was not maxmized');
            })
        })
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is any element on the screen to turn full screen ON, then you can simply click it or use following code:

```
await browser.executeScript('document.documentElement.requestFullscreen();');
```

And, to exit the full screen you can use document object as:

```
 await browser.executeScript('document.exitFullscreen();');
```

OR

```
await browser.executeScript('document.webkitExitFullscreen()');
```